# How to open most recent SublimeText from command line with zsh?

Tags: macos, zsh, sublimetext

I'm having issues opening up sublime from my terminal. I've tried a lot of different methods such as watching YouTube videos or reading similar posts from this website and other blogs. However, from my research alone, it seems that the solutions I've read are from several years back. I want to use the command "subl" to automatically open up files from my command line but I keep hitting roadblocks.

So far,  here is some of the info and methods that I have have tried out:

**First:**

```
echo $Shell 
returns : /bin/zsh
```

**Second:**

(I dragged the application from finder and dropped it into to terminal to figure out where it was located and this is what it returned)

```
returned: /Applications/Sublime\ Tex\ 3.apps
```

**Third:**

```
cd ~
ls -A
open .zshrc
```

(this is what it says when the text window opens up)

```
`export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"
```

**Fourth:**

I tried using this command line for .zsh shell from sublime website

```
echo 'export PATH="/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zprofile

returned : 
 permission denied: /Applications/Sublime Text 3.app
```

**Fifth:**

```
 ln -s "/Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 3.app" /usr/local/bin/subl
returns:
ln: /usr/local/bin/subl: File exist
subl
zsh: command not found: subl
```

**Sixth**

```
echo $PATH
returns:
/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin:/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

Afterwards proceeded to paste this code from online source:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl

returns : 
ln: /usr/local/bin/subl: File exists
```

In the end, nothing that I have tried works. Even when I open my terminal and type

```
subl
returns:
zsh: command not found: subl
```

or

```
subl hello.py 
zsh: command not found: subl
```

or

```
subl --version 
zsh: command not found: sublime
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you download Sublime Text 3 or Sublime Text 4? v.4 is the latest version, and the one you should be using. Its name should be just `Sublime Text.app`.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need the most up-to-date version of Sublime Text. Go to https://www.sublimetext.com/download and click on the `macOS` link at the very top. Unzip the downloaded file, which should happen automatically when you double-click on it, and move `Sublime Text.app` (you may just see it as `Sublime Text` in Finder) to `Applications`. If you get a warning about replacing files, make sure you click the <kbd>Replace</kbd> button.

Now, go to Terminal and enter:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/subl
```

You'll have to enter your password. Next, enter:

```
sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl
```

and you should be all set.

Comment: Hi. I tried your method and I still have not been able to get sublime text to open from my command terminal. I appreciate your help. After the entire process, my command terminal still says

Comment: zsh: command not found: subl

Answer (score 1):

The new Macs are on zsh. According to [Sublime Text's Command Line Documentation](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/command_line.html#mac) We can type the following commands to get subl.

Step 1:

```
echo 'export PATH="/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zprofile
```

Step 2:

```
touch ~/.zprofile
source ~/.zprofile
```

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used SublimeText before, but I was able to get it to work immediately, by doing this:

0. Make sure you have [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) installed.
1. On the command line, run

   ```sh
   brew install --cask sublime-text
   ```
2. Done. That's all there is to it.

Now you can type

```sh
subl .zshrc
```

and it will open your `.zshrc` file in SublimeText.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I tried your method and received this error

Comment: Error: It seems there is already a Binary at '/usr/local/bin/subl'.

Comment: Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Because you have already installed it in some other way. Uninstall your previous SublimeText installation, then install it with Homebrew instead.